# jQuery change does not trigger even when forced

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm having difficulties with getting the .change() event in jQuery to trigger when I change the value of a select drop down. I've already searched for a possible solution though the ones I came across do not seem to work for me...

Basically I have an event on a site which is set as a variable product in WooCommerce, with different time slots. I have written a reasonably complex algorithm to detect whether the maximum number of people have taken that time slot in order to let the user know that the time and date they want is available or not. That part works, though I need to add a trigger on the time slot drop down in order to fire the check.

For debugging purposes I did this:

```
$('#time-slot').on('change', function() {
    console.log("changed");
});
```

Where '#time-slot' is the ID of the select box. However, this does not seem to trigger the console.log text when I change the select. I even tried the following in my console:

```
$('#time-slot').trigger('change');
```

But the "changed" text did not appear in my console.

Then I changed my code so that it would trigger on a click instead. In my console now:

```
$('#time-slot').trigger('click');
```

And this time the text appeared in my console just fine - I even tried it with various other random events such as mouseup, mousedown and focus each time manually triggering the event and every other one worked - except change which is the one I really need.

Is change no longer supported? Or is it that I'm coding it incorrectly? The version of jQuery I am using is 1.11.3.

Hopefully there is a simple solution that maybe I'm just overlooking!

Thank you

Comment: It seems to be working... https://jsfiddle.net/Lwecfu9n/ Is the selectbox already on the page when the `change` event is bound? If not, try `$(document).on('change', '#time-slot', function() {...});` (event delegation)

Comment: Perhaps try `$('#time-slot').change(function() { //code here  });`
Then trigger by calling `$('#time-slot').change()`;